# How do I convert a list of byte literals into string literals in python 3?

Tags: python, string, byte, decode, literals

I have a list of byte literals:

```
list1 = [b'R103', b'R102', b'R109', b'R103']
```

I would like to convert this list of byte literals into string literals. So something like:

```
list1 = ['R103', 'R102', 'R109', 'R103']
```

I have tried using decode:

```
list1.decode("UTF-8")
```

But, decode does not work for lists. I end up with the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Is there a way to convert the entire list to string literals that I am missing?

Comment: Use a list comprehension to `decode` each element individually.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to use list comprehension. In your code example you were trying to apply the function `decode()` on the whole list, as opposed to the elements of that list.
In the below, `list2` is defined by iterating over the elements of `list1`, and converting applying `decode()` to each element, and then creating a new list out of the elements and assigning them to `list2`

```
In [1]: list1 = [b'R103', b'R102', b'R109', b'R103']

In [2]: list2 = [x.decode("UTF-8") for x in list1]

In [3]: list2
Out[3]: ['R103', 'R102', 'R109', 'R103']
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: This gives me an error saying that x is not defined.

Comment: hmmm i just tested in Python 3. it shouldn't error. Maybe there's an error somewhere else?

Comment: Got it! I was converting the contents of list1 into a list when it was already a list.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).